# Want to collect data from all fields in one TX Text Control and save to file in VB6

Tags: vb6

I am storing content of TX to database using code like this:

```
Dim ba() As Byte
Dim FlValue As String

ba = MyTX001.SaveToMemory(5, 0)
FlValue = StrConv(ba, vbUnicode)
MyRS.Fields("mtd001").Value = FlValue

ba = MyTX002.SaveToMemory(5, 0)
FlValue = StrConv(ba, vbUnicode)
MyRS.Fields("mtd002").Value = FlValue
```

Now I want to retrive all the data stored in different fields into one single TX Control (in a two column table) and then save it to a file. The code I am using is something like this:

```
Dim ba() As Byte
Dim RowNum As Long

txTemp.ResetContents
ba = StrConv(MyRS.Fields("mtd001").Value, vbFromUnicode)
txTemp.LoadFromMemory ba, 5, 0
txTemp.SelStart = 0
txTemp.SelLength = -1 'Select all contents

txFinalOutput.TableCellText(CurTableID, RowNum, 2) = txTemp.RTFSelText

txFinalOutput.TableInsertLines txTableInsertAfter, 1  'Add a new Row
RowNum = RowNum + 1


txTemp.ResetContents
ba = StrConv(MyRS.Fields("mtd002").Value, vbFromUnicode)
txTemp.LoadFromMemory ba, 5, 0
txTemp.SelStart = 0
txTemp.SelLength = -1 'Select all contents

txFinalOutput.TableCellText(CurTableID, RowNum, 2) = txTemp.RTFSelText
```

But this is inserting content from DB as RTF text/symbols instead of actual content.

[Link to file that TX TextControl is outputting.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/81x4itc1x2cakc3/YogiTest.zip)

Please help solve this.

Answer (score 0):

A. You should tell us what a tx is. Is is a RichEdit control? The properties don't match eith TOM or a RTF control.

If so, and it looks like it. Look at your last line where you are specifing rtf.

Comment: TX is TX Text Control a third party ActiveX

Answer (score 0):

For a RichTextBox control you can specify wether the data is plain text or if it contains rtf control characters

```
RichTextBox1.LoadFile strFile, rtfRTF
```

Have look at the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa261642%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

Comment: This is not a plain and simle RTF control. It is a specialized Wordprocessing control called TX TextControl. I am not loading text from a file but from a field in a table in DB.

Comment: Ah, sorry I don't know that control. I am afraid I can't help you with it. Sorry.